# How do I convert this curl command for Appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator

I need to convert the following curl command for use in Appcelerator, just can't quite get my head round all the options

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: testing" -G --data-urlencode 'limit=10' --data-urlencode 'where={"location":{"$nearSphere":{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":51.4993541,"longitude":-0.0814079}}}' https://testing.appspot.com/parse/classes/Testing
```

I've tried the following, doesn't give same data as the curl command

```
var l = 'limit=10';
var q = 'where={"location":{"$nearSphere":{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":51.4993541,"longitude":-0.0814079}}}';
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function() {
        callback(false, this.responseText);
    },
    onerror : function() {
        callback(true, this.responseText);
    },
    timeout : 5000
});

xhr.open("GET", parseURL);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", Alloy.Globals.PARSE_APP_ID);
xhr.setRequestHeader("url-encode", l);
xhr.setRequestHeader("url-encode", q);
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could send the query in the header.
For Parse, that looks like you're trying, I'm doing REST requests like this:

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("Done!");
    },
    onerror: function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("Failed. Error: " + e.error);
    }
});
var userIdArray = [user1,user2,user3];

var params = {
    'where': {
        "userid": {
            "$in": userIdArray
        }
    },
    'data': {
        'alert' : _message,
        'badge': 'Increment'
    },
};

xhr.open('POST', 'https://api.parse.com/1/push', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-Application-Id', 'my_parse_id');
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-REST-API-Key', 'my_parse_rest_api_key');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params)); //Remember to stringify them };
```

Note the params inside the xhr.send() method. They have to be stringified ok?
Good luck and let me know if you achieve it!

Comment: Hey Carlos, thanks for the snippet - tried it out with no success, Parse server just returns an "unauthorised" errorI'll tweak it and see if I can work out what's causing error